# composer, show suggested packages

Tags: composer-php

When I run `composer install` the first time, or I add a new package, I see a list of suggested packages, for example:

```
guzzlehttp/psr7 suggests installing zendframework/zend-httphandlerrunner (Emit PSR-7 responses)
grpc/grpc suggests installing ext-protobuf (For better performance, install the protobuf C extension.)
google/protobuf suggests installing ext-bcmath (Need to support JSON deserialization)
google/auth suggests installing phpseclib/phpseclib (May be used in place of OpenSSL for signing strings or for token management. Please require version ^2.)
monolog/monolog suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Allow sending log messages to AWS services like DynamoDB)
monolog/monolog suggests installing doctrine/couchdb (Allow sending log messages to a CouchDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing elasticsearch/elasticsearch (Allow sending log messages to an Elasticsearch server via official client)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-amqp (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server (1.0+ required))
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-mongodb (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server (via driver))
monolog/monolog suggests installing graylog2/gelf-php (Allow sending log messages to a GrayLog2 server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing mongodb/mongodb (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server (via library))
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-amqplib/php-amqplib (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server using php-amqplib)
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-console/php-console (Allow sending log messages to Google Chrome)
monolog/monolog suggests installing rollbar/rollbar (Allow sending log messages to Rollbar)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ruflin/elastica (Allow sending log messages to an Elastic Search server)
google/cloud-core suggests installing opis/closure (May be used to serialize closures to process jobs in the batch daemon. Please require version ^3.)
google/cloud-core suggests installing symfony/lock (Required for the Spanner cached based session pool. Please require the following commit: 3.3.x-dev#1ba6ac9)
google/cloud-translate suggests installing ext-grpc (The gRPC extension enables use of the performant gRPC transport)
google/cloud-translate suggests installing ext-protobuf (Provides a significant increase in throughput over the pure PHP protobuf implementation. See https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc for installation instructions.)
```

How can see this list again, to see if I installed everything I need or I still miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#suggests) `composer suggests` :

`Lists all packages suggested by currently installed set of packages. You can optionally pass one or multiple package names in the format of vendor/package to limit output to suggestions made by those packages only.`

Comment: Thanks. Note: add `-v` for more details